# How to make if-then statement in sed

Tags: regex, linux, if-statement, sed

I am simply trying to add an if-then statement to a sed search. In regex it is `(?(?=phrase)then_code|else_code)`.

Here is the equivalent regex code that I have:

```
"[^"]*"(?(?=,)[^.]*.|[^!]*!)
```

Which matches the following:

blah blah blah `"Hello", Bob said`. Blah blah blah
`"Goodbye"!` blah blah blah

Note: please don't ask about the practicality of this example; The real code is practical.

How would I search that in sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax, as far as I'm aware, only exists in Perl regular expressions.  You'll have to use the [`psed`](http://perldoc.perl.org/psed.html) program, which as its name implies, is a `sed` program written in Perl (and thus using Perl's regex engine).  I believe it comes with the Perl distribution; one way or another, it ended up in my PATH.

You can also just use Perl directly with the `-p`, `-i`, and `-e` arguments to run arbitrary Perl code against every line in some set of files:

```
$ (echo one; echo two; echo three) | perl -p -i -e 's/t/q/g'
one
qwo
qhree
```

See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).